# O que é Grafismo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um plugin, que me da ferramentas que aquele site usa, em uma delas, ele aparece isso: **Grafismo JavaScript** o que seria isso no caso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Grafismo, criar gráficos no javascript, normalmente se usa SVG ou Canvas, no site a cima está o conteúdo relacionado: http://nvd3.org/

Comment: Cara nesse plugin basta vc clicar no que deseja que ele te joga para uma tela onde tem a referencia de tudo que ele lista. Basta ir no site oficial e ler... https://www.wappalyzer.com/categories/javascript-graphics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Wappalyzer categoriza alguns Frameworks como "Grafismo JavaScript", isso é uma categorização dele, e exite uma lista imensa que vc pode conferir aqui:https://www.wappalyzer.com/technologies no entanto no site oficial eles não deixam claro como fazem essa categorização dos Frameworks...

A listagem dos "Grafismo JavaScript" vc pode conferir aqui:
https://www.wappalyzer.com/categories/javascript-graphics

Inclusive eles fornecem um gráfico sobre o uso das tecnologias que eles consideram como "Grafismo JavaScript".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na janela que vc postou na pergunta basta clicar sobre cada uma das Tecnologias que vc vai para a página onde tem a referencia do que é cada coisa.

Por exemplo: https://www.wappalyzer.com/technologies/d3 (repare que a esquerda tem o link oficial do desenvolvedor)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

São APIs pra gerar gráficos com estatisticas de modo prático e rápido em base de informações que você quiser passar.

São ótimos pra sistemas de comunidades e portais de downloads, ou outras finalidades, exatamente como sistemas de planilhas como Excel, só que voltado pra WEB tornando acesseivel para a maioria dos navegadores.

Além do que os softwares faz ele pode ser costumizado e animado sem precisar desenhar nada em softwares de desenho.

[NVD3](http://nvd3.org/examples/index.html)

Exemplo: http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html

[D3.js](https://d3js.org/)

Exemplo: https://bl.ocks.org/ravi4j/0e9a69a81bb8ccf989e6715df9931890